# Ionic v2 - How to disable popover animation

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, popover

I would like to disable the animation that open a Popover starting from Top Left corner. Instead I want it opens the same way it close when I do "dismiss", a sort of a FadeOut of the entire element.

I am not able to do this. It is not clear if I can pass any options to the "create" method.

[Popover official doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/popover/popover-transitions.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable animation by [NavOptions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navoptions)

```
let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create("YourPage");
popover.present({animate: false});
```

You can also change the type of animation. See the doc for more information.

Comment: Thx, this works very well. I was also trying to change the type of the animation but I was not able. According with the docs, this should be the parameters: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#pop but It is not clear all the possible values that are accepted. I used some I found in various examples online, but the popover doesn't open.

Comment: @FlavioSpugna: From the doc: *The property 'animation' understands the following values: md-transition, ios-transition and wp-transition*